# В каком предложении допущена пунктуционная ошибка?

Tags: пунктуация

1) желтые, розовые и синеватые цветы пестрили живой ковер травы, точно рассыпанные самоцветные камни
2) у тебя брошка, вроде как пчелка
3) богат, хорош,собою, Ленский везде был принят как жених
4) пусть наш лежал по узкой и прямой, как линейка, проселочной дороге

Answer (score 3):

Ошибка во **втором** предложении. Запятая там не нужна, так как ВРОДЕ КАК ПЧЁЛКА - это **сказуемое** (со значением сравнения), а не обособленное обстоятельство.

***Добавлю из Розенталя.*** Правда, речь пойдёт об отсутствии тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, но чеховский пример приводится.
*Тире обычно не ставится, хотя подлежащее и сказуемое выражены именительным падежом существительного:
б)      в простых по составу предложениях разговорного стиля речи, например: Моя сестра студентка;
б)      если между подлежащим и сказуемым стоят сравнительные союзы как, будто, словно, точно, все равно как, все равно что, вроде как и т.п., например: Пруд как блестящая сталь (Фет); Ты меж сестер словно горлинка белая промежду сизых, простых голубей (Некрасов);* ***У тебя брошка вроде как пчелка (Чехов)***;

Answer (score 0):

Вообще-то прежде всего бросается в глаза запятая между "хорош и собою" в третьем.
Что касается второго предложения, то боюсь, что она там не абсолютно невозможна. Может по авторской мысли оно тут и не сказуемое вовсе, а отдельное предложение. В разговорной речи возможно нечто подобное "У тебя лицо сияет, вроде как победа?" 
Конечно, выглядит такая трактовка странновато, но формально возможна.